# Looking for a basic auto-ping power watchdog for my flaky server

Tags: electrical-power, watchdog

My home Mac Mini server keeps locking up, and I was looking into a switch to automatically cycle the power when it stops responding to pings. Is there a simpler/cheaper alternative that devices like [iBoot](http://dataprobe.com/iboot-remote-reboot.php) that do more than I need (remote monitoring/control).

(Still looking into the cause of the freezes, but I'm guessing it's the webcam software.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have another host on your home network, try out the mtr tool, it's distributed with many flavors of Linux, and you can set an interval to ping with:

```
 mtr --interval=10 MacMini
```

Comment: I could leave a laptop on if that would solve it, but I'm still lacking a way to reboot the dead server.